# I want the iPhone app(under development) to be able to read setup files?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am writing an iPhone App that has many different setup files that may change over time.  Right now I build the app with the setup file attached.  But since over time things will change I would prefer to be able to have the App read a setup file.  Is there any way to implement that?

Thanks

(If I email users setup files, how/what methodology can be used so they could incorporate it in the execution of the app) ??

Comment: And where should that setup file reside in that case?

Comment: What do you mean by "setup file"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about standard app settings and defaults, you should really look into the NSUserDefaults data type. There's a great blog post about it from Ganbaru Games here:

http://ganbarugames.com/2011/02/how-to-save-data-with-nsuserdefaults/